# LINQ query to Xml- gives Exception 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: linq-to-xml

Here is the query

```
XDocument application = XDocument.Load(@".\..\..\XmlFile\" + xmlFileName); 
var elements = from p in application.Descendants("Function")
               where ((string)p.Attribute("Fnumber").Value.Trim() ==  (SourceCodeParser.fCount.ToString().Trim()) && (string)p.Attribute("MethodName").Value.Trim() == (methodName) && (string) p.Parent.Parent.Attribute("ClassName").Value.Trim()== (className))
               select p.Element("MethodDependencies");
```

Below is the code snippet to execute the query that throws exception

```
foreach (var file in elements)
{
    file.Add(
        new XElement("MethodDependency",
            new XAttribute("MethodName", MethodName),
            new XAttribute("ObjectName", ObjectName),
            new XAttribute("CallNumber", SourceCodeParser.methodcallCount.ToString().Trim()),
            new XElement("Arguments")
       ));
}
```

Here is the Xml Structure

```
<Classes>
  <Class ClassName="" ClassPath="" ModifiedDate="" CreationDate="" InheritedFrom="" Modifier="" Specifier="">
      <Functions>
        <Function ReturnType="" Fnumber="" AccessModifier="" AccessSpecifier="" MethodName="">
          <Dependencies />
          <MethodDependencies />
        </Function>
      </Functions>
  </Class>
</Classes>
```

This query works well for other files but throws exception on some although the code is same for all files...

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the line that throws the exception?

Comment: This statement throws exception,

        foreach (var file in elements)

i debugged the code, as elements did not contain any value. It works well for other files but throws exception on some file. I also checked that in 
  
        XDocument application = XDocument.Load(@".\..\..\XmlFile\" + xmlFileName);
 
application variable, Xml file loaded. query executes and returns null and than foreach statement throws exception.

Comment: Replace `(string) p.Parent.Parent.Attribute("ClassName").Value.Trim()` with `((string)p.Parent.Parent.Attribute("ClassName"))`.Trim() - you are probably missing an attribute somewhere and .Value throws. (string) explicit conversion operator will return string.Empty if the attribute is missing.

Comment: @Pawel `(string)XAttribute` return `null` when attribute is `null`, not `string.Empty`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: You are right - I stand corrected. It is null. To get the empty string one needs to use the '??' operator. Thanks for pointing this out.